# SQL Server 2000 - How to create a new table in existing database with prefix dbo?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

All existing tables are with prefix **dbo.TableNames**

When I create a new table, it creates as **login.MyTable** instead of **dbo.MyTable**.

The screenshot is Security > Properties of my login.

Could you please show me step by step (I am not familiar with SQL securites) how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: To create a table in a specific schema (in fact anytime you create a table), you can and should specify the schema prefix explicitly. e.g. `CREATE TABLE dbo.Table(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means your default schema is your username (assuming that you mean `login` is actually a username like `win` and not **really** `login`). If you're using the UI table designers it will select that schema for you. You can try using:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableName (
  -- some columns
);
```

But you may not have access to the `dbo` schema.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It created as xxx.MyTable (xxx is my login name). I used the same login to create those existing table with dbo prefix. I don't how I messed it up.

Comment: Just as a matter of best practice, you shouldn't be placing user tables in the `dbo` schema anyway. But at least your problem is solved...

Comment: When I use your script to create a table, it let me create with dbo prefix. However, when I create a table in design mode, it created with xxx.MyTable.

Comment: If you press F4 to open the properties in the designer you can select the schema you want the table created in, if you really **must** use the designers.

Comment: Script it out in design mode, make the schema change, then run that in SSMS.

Comment: Awesome, now I know how to create a table with dbo prefix in design mode. Thank you so much, Yuck & Jason!

Comment: @win, you should not ever be creating tables in the designer. Tables should always be created with scripts that are kept in source control.

Comment: just to point out that schema is the wrong word for SQL Server 2000, it does not have schemas it has owners.

Comment: HLGEM & Jason - From now on, I'll generate a script in design mode, and run in SSMS. Thank you for the tip. :)